# Datatable price column sort not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I used the following code for datatable:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
        { "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [ 5 ] }
    ],
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );
```

Here for the 5th column. I used the sort type as 'numeric', but the sorting is not working for this column. The column values are:

```
$205.22
$247.24
$869.95 
$215
......
```

What's wrong here? Please help me.

Comment: your not store the $ in the db are you ?

Comment: $ symbol is manually added by me before the price. In BD it is in 'Float' type

Comment: which, of the very many, jquerry sorting plugins is this? the one i use sorts 'prices' just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A dollar sign isn't numeric. That might be your problem.

I believe datatables offers a [currency sorting plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection).

edit in response: Add the dollar sign after you finish the sort (or look into the currency sorting plugin I mentioned)

Comment: If i remove the $ symbol the sorting is working fine. But i need the $ symbol here. Is there any possiblity?

Comment: edit the js to remove the $ for sorting. or get a better one that does it for you.